# Using wkhtmltopdf from a web page

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am looking for a solution to producing a `pdf` document from a web page and have read the good reviews of `wkhtmltopdf`. I might be missing something but it appears that it is only run from the command line on the machine being used. I have a site that is predominantly `php`, for which there is a log in, and a number of session variables and queries from a database are used to produce the html output. What I am looking for is a means by which I can add a single button on the `html` page created to generate the `pdf` version.

Also, while I have installed `wkhtmltopdf` locally and tested it out from the command line I can't see how can you call on the function from where my site is hosted.

I have used `HTML2PDf` in the past but it struggled with tables and so thought I would give `wkhtmltopdf` a go but I am not sure it will meet my needs. Can it do what I am asking of it?